# Find the brightest contour opencv java

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-studio

i am trying to capture the brightest area with camera.

am using opencv and android studio (JAVA). so far there is limited resources and documentation on opencv with regards to java.

am a newbie programmer, so any advice would be helpful.

tried to debug my code but can't seem to get beyond this like of code

```
Core.MinMaxLocResult max = minMaxLoc(wrapper);
```

Does anyone know how to properly use the MinMaxLocResult function in JAVA??

and also is there a more efficient way of finding the brightest area in a frame??

my code
`
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

```
    Log.e(TAG, "on camera frame ");
    Mat mHierarchy = new Mat();
    mGrey = inputFrame.gray();
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    //find contour
```

Imgproc.findContours(mGrey,Mcontours,mHierarchy,Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

```
    double maxMax=0;
    int num=0;

    for(int x = 0; x < Mcontours.size();x++){
        Mat wrapper = Mcontours.get(x);

        Core.MinMaxLocResult max = minMaxLoc(wrapper); **//error line**

        if(max.maxVal > maxMax){
            maxMax = max.maxVal;
            num = x;
        }
            if(x == Mcontours.size()){
                Imgproc.circle(mGrey,max.maxLoc,5,CONTOUR_COLOR);
                Imgproc.drawContours(mGrey,Mcontours,num,CONTOUR_COLOR);
            }

    }
```

return mGrey
}
`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the biggest contour check out my code:

```
mContours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
mObjectContours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();

private void findObjectContour(Mat src) {
    mContours.clear();
    Imgproc.findContours(src, mContours, mHierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    filterContoursArea(mContours);
}

private void filterContoursArea(List<MatOfPoint> mContours) {
    double maxArea = getMaxContourArea(mContours);
    mObjectContours.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < mContours.size(); i++) {
        MatOfPoint contour = mContours.get(i);
        if (Imgproc.contourArea(contour) > mMinContourArea * maxArea) {
            mObjectContours.add(contour);
        }
    }
}

private double getMaxContourArea(List<MatOfPoint> contours) {
    double maxArea = 0;
    double area;
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        area = Math.abs(Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i)));
        if (area > maxArea) {
            maxArea = area;
        }
    }
    return maxArea;
}

private int calculateMaxContourAreaIdx(List<MatOfPoint> contours) {
    double maxArea = 0;
    int maxHandContourAreaIdx = 0;
    double area;
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        area = Math.abs(Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i)));
        if (area > maxArea) {
            maxArea = area;
            maxHandContourAreaIdx = i;
        }
    }
    return maxHandContourAreaIdx;
}
```